# Downloading a file from web using Powershell

Tags: powershell

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to download a csv file using Powershell. If I am use a public link, I am able to download the file.

But when I am trying to download from my account (private link), the file downloads and I am getting some sort of html/css content. Screenshot is attached. For now, I was testing it with Dropbox. Although, I want to download the file from Huddle Workspace.

I am using two ways as follows:

```
$url = "url/path/to/file/Notification.csv"
$output = "pathToFolder/Notification.csv"
$wc = New-Object System.net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url,$output) 

$cred = Get-Credential -UserName 'myEmailAddress@hotmail.com'
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $output -Credential $cred
```

Again, both methods works with Public link. What would be the best way to add credentials and download the file. Thanks

Comment: Authentication can differ between services, using an official API would be my choice in this situation. You deal with authentication in a way that each service supports and often they are easier to use aswell. Take a look at the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs) and the [Huddle API](https://github.com/Huddle/huddle-apis/wiki).

Comment: I am no Web Developer, but as far I understand you do not have a session. It will work fine with public (unsecured/no login required) pages. The HTML content you are getting is probably for the login page. You want to try Huddle API's for this... https://github.com/Huddle/huddle-apis/wiki

Comment: Yea you are right. API would be helpful. Actually I did request for Huddle API and I am waiting for their response. Meanwhile, I was just trying without API if it was possible but so far no luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys